# Return sorted directory folders by name

Tags: c#, sorting, directoryinfo

I have a directory path c:\W with a list of folders in it -

```
01_C
02_B
03_A
04_F
```

I would like the directory folders sorted and returned with below output -

```
A
B
C
F
```

I am using .net 4.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask] a couple of times..

Comment: At the moment I use directoryinfo getdirectories method to loop through folders and use substring to remove first part of folder name. Dont know how to sort it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to sort on the Last character of your directory name then:

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\w");
List<string> dirList = di.GetDirectories()
                         .Select(r => r.Name)
                         .OrderBy(r => r[r.Length - 1])
                         .ToList();
```

Remember to include `using System.Linq`  on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\W");
var sorted = d.GetDirectories().Select(f => f.Name.Split('_')[1]).OrderBy(name => name);
```

Please note that there isn't any error handling here, just an idea to get you rolling.